# Помогите реализовать бота-игру на aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

И так, я уже какое-то время пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как работает aiogram и недавно решил написать небольшого бота мини-игру.

Упрощённые правила выглядят следующим образом: *"Вначале игры игроку будет дано случайное слово, в течение первых 30 секунд необходимо называть слова, которые начинаются на первые 3 буквы этого слова. По прошествии 30 секунд правила изменятся и ещё пол минуты игрок должен называть слова, которые начинаются на первые 2 буквы слова. После того, как закончатся эти 30 секунд настанет финальная часть игры, где, как вы уже могли догадаться, игроку необходимо будет называть слова начинающиеся на первую букву стартового слова в течение 30 секунд."*

Не могу понять, как реализовать такую функцию, вот что я сейчас имею:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["play", "again"])
async def start_game(message: types.Message):
    global START_WORD
    curr_word = choice(START_WORD)
    await message.answer(text=START_GAME_MESSAGE + curr_word)
 
    list_of_guessed_words = []  
    SCORE = 0
 
    async def handle_stage_one(msg: types.Message):
        nonlocal list_of_guessed_words
        nonlocal SCORE
 
        if msg.text.lower().startswith(curr_word[:3].lower()) and is_word_valid(
            msg.text
        ):
            if msg.text.lower() not in list_of_guessed_words:
                list_of_guessed_words.append(msg.text.lower())
                SCORE += len(msg.text) * 3
                await msg.answer(f"Подходит! Ваш текущий счет: {SCORE}")
            else:
                await msg.answer("Слово уже было угадано.")
        else:
            await msg.answer("Не подходит.")
 
    dp.register_message_handler(handle_stage_one, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
 
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
 
    dp.unregister_message_handler(handle_stage_one)
 
    await message.answer(
        "30 секунд прошло, началась вторая стадия игры, называйте слова, начинающиеся на первые 2 буквы стартового слова!"
    )
 
    async def handle_stage_two(msg: types.Message):
        nonlocal list_of_guessed_words
        nonlocal SCORE
 
        if msg.text.lower().startswith(curr_word[:2].lower()) and is_word_valid(
            msg.text
        ):
            if msg.text.lower() not in list_of_guessed_words:
                list_of_guessed_words.append(msg.text.lower())
                SCORE += len(msg.text) * 2
                await msg.answer(f"Подходит! Ваш текущий счет: {SCORE}")
            else:
                await msg.answer("Слово уже было угадано.")
        else:
            await msg.answer("Не подходит.")
 
    dp.register_message_handler(handle_stage_two, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
 
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
 
    dp.unregister_message_handler(handle_stage_two)
 
    await message.answer(
        "Ещё 30 секунд прошло, началась последняя стадия игры, называйте слова, начинающиеся на первую букву стартового слова!"
    )
 
    async def handle_stage_three(msg: types.Message):
        nonlocal list_of_guessed_words
        nonlocal SCORE
 
        if msg.text.lower().startswith(curr_word[:1].lower()) and is_word_valid(
            msg.text
        ):
            if msg.text.lower() not in list_of_guessed_words:
                list_of_guessed_words.append(msg.text.lower())
                SCORE += len(msg.text) * 1
                await msg.answer(f"Подходит! Ваш текущий счет: {SCORE}")
            else:
                await msg.answer("Слово уже было угадано.")
        else:
            await msg.answer("Не подходит.")
 
    dp.register_message_handler(
        handle_stage_three, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT
    )

    await asyncio.sleep(30)
 
    dp.unregister_message_handler(handle_stage_three)
 
    await message.answer(f"Игра окончена. Ваши результаты: {SCORE}")
```

здесь можно посмотреть полный код, если это будет полезно:
https://pastebin.com/c6JHcAjy

я пытался реализовать это короче через цикл, но тогда бот не реагировал совершенно. Этот dp.unregister_message_handler(handle_stage_one) подсказал мне gpt чат, но как я понял, такого атрибута как unregister вообще не существует у dispetcher'а, так что он здесь просто для обозначения чего я хочу сделать.

Проблема сейчас заключается в том, что после начала игры срабатывает первая функция, проверяющая слово по правилам первого раунда игры, но при переходе на второй раунд правила проверки не меняются и слова не засчитываются.

Подскажите, пожалуйста как можно решить проблему, или хотя бы укажите направление. Может есть что-то более конкретное, чем мануалы aiogram, что бы я мог почитать, так как в них я закопался уже и не нашёл пока что ничего что бы могло решить эту задачу.
Благодарен любому, кто до сюда вообще дочитал.